# AppExchange Apps - Security Concerns on embedding URLs with Encrypted Short Lived Access Tokens

Tags: appexchange, security-review, urlhacking, lightning-container

We are working on an AppExchange App which integrates with external application at the UI Layer.
External application (composite app) has different widgets which we can embed within AppExchange Aura Component using Lightning Container.

The external application (composite app) widgets are built in such a way that they can be integrated with any platform.

Currently it provides authentication as below:

- Generate the short lived access_token from External (Composite) app.
- Pass the short lived access_token **(Encrypted)**  in the widget URL which we are loading in the Lightning Container. Also other parameters to load the widget are passed in encrypted format.
- External Widget will be loaded within container.

**Question:**
As the widget needs access_token **(Encrypted)** in the URL, it may be seen as a security concern (sensitive information in URL).
However, as the external system's access_token is short lived and encrypted, can this approach be considered as secure?